# $\frac{\partial A(x, y)}{\partial x} = B(x)A(x, y), \; \frac{\partial A(x, y)}{\partial y} = -A(x, y)B(y), \; A(x,x)=I \implies A(x,y)A(y,z)=A(x,z)$

Tags: matrices

Given functions $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ and $B: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ where $$\frac{\partial A(x, y)}{\partial x} = B(x)A(x, y) \quad \text{and} \quad  \frac{\partial A(x, y)}{\partial y} = -A(x, y)B(y)$$

such that $ A(x,x)=I $, I need to prove this implies $A(x,y)A(y,z)=A(x,z)$.

Edit:  I was asked to explain what I've done so far.

First I tried using solely the property $A(x,x)=I$ to derive some properties of $A(x,y)_{ij}=a_{ij}(x,y)$ like $$a_{ii}(x,x)=1 \implies a_{ii}(x,y)= \frac{f(x)}{f(y)} $$ for some function $f$ and then use this to solve the problem by looking at $$(A(x,y)A(y,z))_{ij}=\sum_{k}a_{ik}(x,y)a_{kj}(y,z)$$ but that was a dead end.

I then looked at $$\frac{\partial A_{ij}(x, x)}{\partial x}=\sum_k b_{ik}(s)a_{kj}(x,x)=0$$ and saw that this implies $\text{tr}(B(x))=0$ but I don't know if this has any significance. I don't really know what else to do.

Edit 2:
I can't seem to get on to the "bill" account sorry. Maybe I should delete this and ask again?

Comment: What do you think about the problem?

Comment: @Bill, you should log in with your original account to edit the problem to include what you have done.